# Call to undefined method Auth::user()->can() in laravel 8 error

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I have a problem with determining the permission with Auth::user()->can().
For example Auth::user()->can('trunk.index) returns always error;

But I have a problem.
If I dump $user->getPermissionsViaRoles(); ,I will get a large result.

I'm using different table user_view table.
And according to it I have changed in Auth.php file. and login is working fine.

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'self-eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\UserView::class,
        ]
    ],
```

But when I try to check permission the via Auth::user()->can('trunk.index) then it gives error below error.

```
Call to undefined method App\\Models\\UserView::can()
```

Below is my UserView model code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Laravel\Lumen\Auth\Authorizable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens; 

class UserView extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{
    use Authenticatable;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasRoles;
    use HasApiTokens;
    protected $table = 'user_view';
    protected $primaryKey = "user_id";

    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'password',
    ];

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return ['password' => $this->attributes['user_password']];
    }

    // public function can($abilities, $arguments = []) {
        
    // }

}
```

help me if I'm missing something. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a custom `User` model which does not implement the `\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable` interface and `\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate\Authorizable` trait. You do actually have an import for this interface, but it is not used anywhere.

Also be careful about the existing import `Laravel\Lumen\Auth\Authorizable`. I'm not familiar with Lumen, but this might be a different implementation / wrong import.

---

You essentially need to update your model with the following two lines:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;             // <-- add import
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens; 

class UserView extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                        AuthorizableContract    // <-- add interface
{
    use Authenticatable;
    use Authorizable;                                           // <-- add trait
    use HasFactory;
    use HasRoles;
    use HasApiTokens;

    // ... other code ...
}
```

Comment: also, Lumen is not recommended anymore :)

Comment: I have removed Laravel\Lumen\Auth\Authorizable from my code.  Can you edit my model and add relaeted code.

Comment: Hello @OMiShah Can you please help me to figure out this problem. I have added given interface to my model. do I need to implement can() method in my model?

Comment: @NishaPatel, no idea about Lumen. May be you need to implement your own custom ``can`` method in User model class file. :)

Comment: @NishaPatel I've updated my answer with a code snippet. It really is no rocket science.